# Shield UI GRID ASP.NET CORE MVC

Tags: sql, entity-framework, asp.net-core, shieldui

I need help on how to use the grid to retrieve and modify data from SQL server database and save it back to the SQL server by using ASP.NET CORE MVC and entityframework CORE

In other words 
I get the data from SQL database using the CONTEXT class and save it to an IEnumerable variable and send it to the View to be displayed 
I want the user to be able to edit this data using the GRID and send it back to the controller to update the SQL server database like the entityframework

Can you provide an example ?

Thanks
Mo

Answer (score 0):

You can create [Web API REST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-3.0) services that perform CRUD operations on the data and then configure the Grid as in [this example](https://demos.shieldui.com/web/grid-editing/editing-restful-web-service), to work with the remote endpoints when Creating, Reading, Updating or Deleting the data.